# OpenStack installer fails, but node has 'Deployed' status?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I'm trying to setup a cloud with Openstack. As the [official MAAS Ubuntu Cloud documentation](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud) has very brief steps, it's taken me just under a month of on and off work to get to this stage of an installation.
I must have had 50 attempts of removing, re-adding, and re-commissioning nodes due to all the trial and error processes I've been through...

Anyway, I finally got to the point of deploying my first node this evening! I commissioned a test node and ran `sudo openstack-install` to start the installation process. It ran for about 15-20 minutes and the node now has a 'deployed' status, but the installation had failed once again. Here's the error I got from the MAAS error log:

```
joel@ubuntu-maas-controller:~/.juju$ cat ~/.cloud-install/*.log
[INFO: 11-02 18:31:34, openstack-install:227] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.28
[INFO: 11-02 18:31:34, openstack-install:228] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 11-02 18:31:34, openstack-install:239] Creating juju directories: /home/joel/.cloud-install/juju
[INFO: 11-02 18:31:35, openstack-install:295] Running Liberty release
[INFO: 11-02 18:31:53, installbase.py:132] Performing an Autopilot install
[INFO: 11-02 18:31:53, utils.py:780] pollinate: sudo su - -c 'pollinate -q -r --curl-opts "-k --user-agent uoi/8b82a068-2aca-4034-931b-ad64a320dc96/IL"'
[DEBUG: 11-02 18:32:14, landscape.py:75] Existing MAAS defined, doing a LDS installation with existing MAAS.
[DEBUG: 11-02 18:32:24, utils.py:627] ssh keys exist for this user, they will be used instead.
[DEBUG: 11-02 18:32:24, multi.py:139] Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/home/joel/.cloud-install/juju juju  bootstrap 
[DEBUG: 11-02 18:53:05, multi.py:145] Problem during bootstrap: '{'output': '', 'status': 1, 'err': 'Bootstrapping environment "maas"\nStarting new instance for initial state server\nLaunching instance\nWARNING no architecture was specified, acquiring an arbitrary node\n - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-cca09526-a116-11e6-b6cb-001b789e22aa/\nInstalling Juju agent on bootstrap instance\nWaiting for address\nAttempting to connect to free-effect.maas:22\nAttempting to connect to free-effect.maas:22\nAttempting to connect to 10.0.4.32:22\nAttempting to connect to 10.1.1.114:22\nWarning: the ECDSA host key for \'free-effect.maas\' differs from the key for the IP address \'10.1.1.114\'\nOffending key for IP in /home/joel/.ssh/known_hosts:5\nMatching host key in /home/joel/.ssh/known_hosts:6\r\nLogging to /var/log/cloud-init-output.log on remote host\nRunning apt-get update\nRunning apt-get upgrade\nInstalling package: curl\nInstalling package: cpu-checker\nInstalling package: bridge-utils\nInstalling package: rsyslog-gnutls\nInstalling package: cloud-utils\nInstalling package: cloud-image-utils\nInstalling package: tmux\nFetching tools: curl -sSfw \'tools from %{url_effective} downloaded: HTTP %{http_code}; time %{time_total}s; size %{size_download} bytes; speed %{speed_download} bytes/s \' --retry 10 -o $bin/tools.tar.gz <[https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/agent/1.25.6/juju-1.25.6-trusty-amd64.tgz]>\nTimeout, server free-effect.maas not responding.\r\nERROR failed to bootstrap environment: subprocess encountered error code 255\nSessions still open, not unmounting\n'}'
[ERROR: 11-02 18:53:05, gui.py:269] A fatal error has occurred: Problem with juju bootstrap.

[ERROR: 11-02 18:53:05, gui.py:270] Problem with juju bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 54, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 146, in do_install
    raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.
[DEBUG: 11-02 18:53:05, error.py:35] showing error view for: Problem with juju bootstrap.
[ERROR: 11-02 18:53:36, ev.py:130] Exception in ev.run():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ev.py", line 128, in run
    self.loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 278, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 376, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 1326, in run
    self._loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 276, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1172, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/events.py", line 120, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 393, in <lambda>
    event_loop, callback, self.get_available_raw_input())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 493, in parse_input
    callback(processed, processed_codes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 403, in _update
    self.process_input(keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 503, in process_input
    k = self._topmost_widget.keypress(self.screen_size, k)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/gui.py", line 136, in keypress
    return super().keypress(size, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1128, in keypress
    return self.body.keypress( (maxcol, remaining), key )
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 836, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress((maxcol,), key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1587, in keypress
    key = self.focus.keypress(tsize, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 621, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress(maxvals, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1587, in keypress
    key = self.focus.keypress(tsize, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/wimp.py", line 535, in keypress
    self._emit('click')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/widget.py", line 463, in _emit
    signals.emit_signal(self, name, self, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 264, in emit
    result |= self._call_callback(callback, user_arg, user_args, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 294, in _call_callback
    return bool(callback(*args_to_pass))
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ui/views/error.py", line 66, in cancel
    raise SystemExit("Install exited because of error.")
SystemExit: Install exited because of error.
[DEBUG: 11-02 18:53:37, utils.py:59] Juju Version: 1.25.6-trusty-amd64
[INFO: 11-02 18:53:37, utils.py:61] Cleanup, saving latest config object.
joel@ubuntu-maas-controller:~/.juju$ cat ~/.cloud-install/*.log | more
[INFO: 11-02 18:31:34, openstack-install:227] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.28
[INFO: 11-02 18:31:34, openstack-install:228] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 11-02 18:31:34, openstack-install:239] Creating juju directories: /home/joel/.cloud-install/juju
[INFO: 11-02 18:31:35, openstack-install:295] Running Liberty release
[INFO: 11-02 18:31:53, installbase.py:132] Performing an Autopilot install
[INFO: 11-02 18:31:53, utils.py:780] pollinate: sudo su - -c 'pollinate -q -r --curl-opts "-k --user-agent uoi/8b82a068-2aca-4034-931b-ad64a320dc96/IL"'
[DEBUG: 11-02 18:32:14, landscape.py:75] Existing MAAS defined, doing a LDS installation with existing MAAS.
[DEBUG: 11-02 18:32:24, utils.py:627] ssh keys exist for this user, they will be used instead.
[DEBUG: 11-02 18:32:24, multi.py:139] Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/home/joel/.cloud-install/juju juju  bootstrap 
[DEBUG: 11-02 18:53:05, multi.py:145] Problem during bootstrap: '{'output': '', 'status': 1, 'err': 'Bootstrapping environment "maas"\nStarting new instance for in
itial state server\nLaunching instance\nWARNING no architecture was specified, acquiring an arbitrary node\n - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-cca09526-a116-11e6-b6cb-001
b789e22aa/\nInstalling Juju agent on bootstrap instance\nWaiting for address\nAttempting to connect to free-effect.maas:22\nAttempting to connect to free-effect.ma
as:22\nAttempting to connect to 10.0.4.32:22\nAttempting to connect to 10.1.1.114:22\nWarning: the ECDSA host key for \'free-effect.maas\' differs from the key for
 the IP address \'10.1.1.114\'\nOffending key for IP in /home/joel/.ssh/known_hosts:5\nMatching host key in /home/joel/.ssh/known_hosts:6\r\nLogging to /var/log/cl
oud-init-output.log on remote host\nRunning apt-get update\nRunning apt-get upgrade\nInstalling package: curl\nInstalling package: cpu-checker\nInstalling package:
 bridge-utils\nInstalling package: rsyslog-gnutls\nInstalling package: cloud-utils\nInstalling package: cloud-image-utils\nInstalling package: tmux\nFetching tools
: curl -sSfw \'tools from %{url_effective} downloaded: HTTP %{http_code}; time %{time_total}s; size %{size_download} bytes; speed %{speed_download} bytes/s \' --re
try 10 -o $bin/tools.tar.gz <[https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/agent/1.25.6/juju-1.25.6-trusty-amd64.tgz]>\nTimeout, server free-effect.maas not responding
.\r\nERROR failed to bootstrap environment: subprocess encountered error code 255\nSessions still open, not unmounting\n'}'
[ERROR: 11-02 18:53:05, gui.py:269] A fatal error has occurred: Problem with juju bootstrap.

[ERROR: 11-02 18:53:05, gui.py:270] Problem with juju bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 54, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 146, in do_install
    raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.
[DEBUG: 11-02 18:53:05, error.py:35] showing error view for: Problem with juju bootstrap.
[ERROR: 11-02 18:53:36, ev.py:130] Exception in ev.run():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ev.py", line 128, in run
    self.loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 278, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 376, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 1326, in run
    self._loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 276, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1172, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/events.py", line 120, in _run
```

Is it the download operation that's failing here? I've tried disabling the proxy setting within the MAAS settings (as per the solved reply of [this github issue](https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/1002)) but I'm running out of ideas now and feel like I'm going around in circles.

Edit: I just realised that I **can't** ping the outside network from the node but I **can** nslookup an IP so DNS is kinda working. I assume this must be a networking problem? Will continue my tests and report back if I get anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to guess in all your testing you managed to aquire a free-effect.maas entry in your DNS cache which is no longer the correct host.

Comment: @bc2946088 Do you have any idea how to clear the MAAS DNS cache?

Comment: Well actually, it might not be cached but actually in bind as a host.  I'd check in `/etc/bind/maas/` in the zone file.  Granted, this might not be the problem at all, it's just a thought with the error message you're getting.  I ran into similar problems when I had a failed deployment, and then retried without rebuilding MAAS before hand.

Comment: Did you setup your MAAS server to forward traffic from your lan to wan?  Your DNS would work because it will point from your nodes to your maas server which can resolve hosts for the nodes.